# How to create a Dynamic Web Project with JAX-WS based Web Service in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

How can I create and run a `JAX-WS` web service in a `Dynamic Web Project` using `Eclipse`? I'll be using Tomcat 7 as my server. Can you provide a step by step tutorial on how to do it? A hello world web service will do.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) but I wasn't able to make it run. I did not follow the tutorial's step 4 - 6 because I'm already using Eclipse and the directories are already properly structured on a Dynamic Web Project. Also, my Tomcat is running under JDK 6. Since JAX-WS is already part of JDK 6, there's no need for me to copy it inside Tomcat. When I run the URL indicated in the tutorial, I get a resource not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jax-ws is not part of the JDK. You have to copy the jax-ws implementation into the Tomcat.
Did you find the jax-ws.jar in your JDK folder?

Comment: JAX-WS has become a part of Java since JDK 1.6. Here's an article about it: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jdk_6_update_4_released

Answer (score 1):

Ok, JDK6+JAXWS often gives problems.

You need to create an endorsed-Folder.

Try to run Tomcat from Eclipse. using these additional VM-Arguments:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="<your-server>\endorsed" -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.soap.MetaFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

now, place the latest saaj-impl and saaj-api to the endorsed folder.

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What is an endorsed folder? What does the VM-Arguments means?

Comment: Im not sure ... i think the endorsed jars will be loaded before the JDK loads. So the implementaion of jdk is overwritten. And the two impls are compatible.